# grep linux вывести строку, начинающуюся с последней по алфавиту буквы

Tags: linux, grep

В файле содержатся строки на русском языке. Как можно вывести строку, начинающуюся с последней по списку буквы алфавита?

Comment: 1. какого именно алфавита (глаголица, несколько вариантов кириллицы, или ещё какой-нибудь)? от выбора будет зависеть выбор последней буквы. 2. если таких строк несколько, выводить все или выбрать одну (по какому критерию)? 3. каким образом вы пытались решить поставленную задачу и что именно вызвало затруднения?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил следующим образом:

```
sort -r file | grep - m 1 ''
```

Comment: Проверьте это со словами, начинающимися на "ё". Я точно не помню, но возможно результат будет не соответствовать ожидаемому

Answer (score 0):

Если правильно понял, то это должно помочь

```
$ cat file | grep '^[яЯ]'
```

Comment: или напрямую `grep '^[яЯ]' file`

Comment: *Useless use of cat*!

Comment: в файле не обязательно должна содержаться строка, начинающаяся на "я/Я". проблему решил с помощью sort -r file | grep - m 1 ''